# How to use calibrated Standard Stochastic Volatility?

Tags: volatility, stochastic-volatility

I'm considering the standard stochastic volatility model:

$$x_t = \rho x_{t-1} + \sigma \epsilon_x$$
$$y_t = \beta \exp\left[ \frac{x_t}{2} \right] \epsilon_y$$

where $y_t$ is the log-returns and $x_t$ the log-vol associated to $y_t$.

I used [PMCMC](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf) to estimate $\rho, \sigma, \beta$.

My question is:

My target is to model the volatility of an asset (equity spread) $(p_t)_t$ based on this model. $y_t$ is calculated this way:

$$
y_t = \log(p_t) - \log(p_{t-1})
$$

Now that I estimated the latent variables, I get $x_t$, I don't know how I can get back the volatility of the spread $p_t$.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Please make acronyms like PMCMC explicit or provide a link. Where did you get this volatility model from? Did you estimate an $x_0$ as well or do you assume $x_0 = 0$? You're assuming that the spread is always positive here, it this what you want?

Comment: - This model is the standard stochastic volatility. You can find content on http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6980.pdf (p. 13). I assume $x_0 = 0$. The spread can be positive/negative since it's a linear combination of asset prices (The most important in this analysis is the stationarity of the spread).

Comment: What I think is:
Because 
$p_t | x_t, p_{t-1} = p_{t-1} \exp( N(0, \beta^2 exp(x_t)))$

So with a simple Monte Carlo, I sample from this dist to construct the volatility associated to $p_t$ with regard to $x_t, p_{t-1}$.

Comment: With this model, you have $p_t = p_{t-1} \exp(y_t)$, and this means that if $p_t$ is the price of the spread (as I think you do), then it will never change sign.

Comment: You're right! My model only permits positive values for the spread. So I need another formula to compute the returns. It should be more something like $y_t = |p_t / p_{t-1}| - 1$

Comment: Why don't you simulate the two assets between which you want to see the spread using their own model (could be the one described above) and then simply compute the spread as the difference between them?

Comment: Let's forget one moment about the spread. Let's consider a single positive stock $s_t$. With this SV model, I can get the volatility of the log returns of $s_t$. In the model this quantity is $exp(x_t)$. The thing is, I would like to find the volatility of $s_t$ (and not the vol of the log returns) to model Bollinger Bands.

Answer (score 1):

The volatility of your asset $y_t$ is simply its time varying standard deviation, given by $\beta \exp(x_t/2)$. Once you've got the estimates for latent factor $x_t$ from converged MCMC chain, calculate the expected value for volatility at time $t$ using
$$
\hat{v_t} = \mathbb{E}[\beta \exp(x_t/2)] = \frac{1}{R}\sum_{r=1}^R \beta \exp(x_t^{(r)})
$$
where $R$ is the total number of MCMC chains you've got and $x_t^{(r)}$ is the value of $x_t$ in $r$-th chain.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm more keen on to model the volatility of $p_t$ instead of $y_t$. Do you know how I can proceed?

Comment: $y_t$ is the return, the different between consecutive price $p_t$. So you want to model the volatility of the price instead of return? If that's case, it's typically un-doable because financial price is non-stationary (not refers to heteroskedasticity, but the trending component in a price time series) and the volatility for non-stationary time-series is undefined.

Comment: If you are modelling spread (price difference between different assets at the same time), it has a chance that those two assets are co-integrated (and hence suitable for pair-trading). In that case, you can model the volatility of the spread either by this standard SV model or a regime-switching SV model.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm doing. My spread $p_t$ is stationary.
I use $p_t|x_t,p_{t-1} = p_{t-1} \exp(N(0, \beta^2 \exp(x_t)))$, because $y_t = \log(p_t) - \log(p_{t-1})$ and a simple Monte Carlo method to sample from this dist to have the hidden volatility associated to $p_t$. I can't input $p_t$ to a standard SV model, do I?

Comment: As a matter of fact, my goal is to model the volatility of the spread.

Comment: Then you simply pass that spreads as observations to the SV model. $y_t = s_t = p_t^{(1)} - p_t^{(2)}$

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this one. But I don't know if it will work because, since the spread may be stationary, it has a persistence parameter (the autocorrelation function does not decrease to 0 right away, like log returns would do). This is more than just white noise. So I think that could be a limitation since the model does not account for such a persistence.